# Babel: import modules from outside folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module, babeljs

I had import error

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

for next project structure:

[image: 1]

I prepared simple example on github:
https://github.com/arimanov/babel_test

How I can configure babel for importing modules inside common modules (modules from other top folder)?